# Java Swing application lifecycle problem

Tags: java, swing

I have a Java application which is used to start a Swing user interface. The interface is a class with an encapsulated JFrame instance. The problem is that the application allocates some resources and the Swing interface uses these resources, but the application closes the resource *not* the user interface.

How can I achieve either the main application gets a notification when the complete Swing interface is closed or that the start of the Swing interface blocks until it's closed. Closed means that the [`WindowAdapter.windowClosed(WindowEvent)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html#windowClosed) method of the JFrame WindowListener was already invoked.

The solution from this thread ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341699/how-do-i-make-a-thread-wait-for-jframe-to-close-in-java)) seems to return when the JFrame will be invisble, does this include the `WINDOW_CLOSED` event handling?

**Edit:** Maybe it will be a solution to implement this lifecycle interface:

```
public interface Lifecycle {

    public void startup();

    public void shutdown();

}
```

Now the Swing interface class has to invoke the `shutdown()` method of the main application in the handler of the [WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSED](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html#WINDOW_CLOSED) event.

Is it possible and a good pratice to do so?

Comment: maybe there is your halfway http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080638/basic-java-swing-how-to-exit-and-dispose-of-your-application-jframe/7082054#7082054

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener()`. If you supply appropriate event mask you can get events you need. This is without subscribing to specific instance of JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

The approach should be as follows

- resource closing should raise an event
- The class encapsulated the JFrame, should listen to the resource closing event
- and the listener should call the JFrame.setEnabled(false) method to make it disable

Comment: The class with the JFrame doesn't know about closing the resource, because the closing of this JFrame shall trigger the closing of the resource. Stefan (sry about writing my question so ambiguous)